# Is there an annotation equivalent to the Spring AOP aop:include configuration for autoproxies

Tags: spring, spring-aop

When specifying the XML configuration below:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
    <aop:include name="myBean" />
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
```

We all know that the @EnableAspectJAutoProxy annotation is the equivalent to the aspectj-autoproxy XML configuration but is there a java-based annotation equivalent for the aop:include XML configuration?  I searched extensively and could not find.

Comment: What are you using AspectJ for, most things in Spring can be done without, as most 'wearing' can be done with JDK or CGLib proxies.

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek I am using CGLIB proxies. Do you know the answer to the posted question?

Comment: The short answer no there isn't. All aspects are considered when using java based configuration. Why would you need/want to specify which aspects to take into account? If you really want you could create a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` lookup the definition named `AUTO_PROXY_CREATOR_BEAN_NAME` and specify a list of expression to include. Or you can use profiles to limit the number of aspects.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you tell Spring that you are using a particular feature, like Transaction management and it will create the proxies needed.

For instance `@EnableTransactionManagement` will cause Spring to create proxies for Components (services, controllers and repositories) which use `@Transactional`, you don't need to declare this, Spring automatically finds the beans that need to be proxied.

It works the same way with `@EnableScheduling` causing Spring to detect `@Scheduled` methods, and `@EnableCaching` to detect `@Cached` method.